# Графы на PHP

Tags: php, книги

Прошу помочь дать ссылочку на статью с примерами на PHP, на тему: нахождение кратчайшего пути, теория графов.

Заранее благодарен. Довольно трудно по формулам вышки что-то мне написать, хочется посмотреть, а на пхп не могу найти примеры.

Comment: "а на пхп не могу найти примеры"

Что вполне естественно. Также сложно найти пособия по копанию земли топором (или рубки леса лопатой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Реализация поиска в графе на PHP](http://cleonty.narod.ru/articles/graph.html)

> Первое, что нужно сделать, это выбрать способ представления данного графа в сценарии PHP. Один из подходов заключается в использовании встроенных типов данных и функций поиска. Тестовый скрипт строит контрольный граф просто как словарь: каждое состояние является ключом словаря со списком ключей узлов, в которые из него можно попасть (то есть его дуг). В этом скрипте определена функция, с помощью которой мы выполним поиск на графе...

Comment: очень хороший пример, но там показно как пройти из 1 точки в точку 2, а что если у меня машрут из 5 или 10 точек ? как проложить путь ?
Как можно подрправить что бы я задачал несколько точек и он прокладывал маршрут между ними. Хочу решить задачу, что грузоперевозхчик должен объезжать склад с несколькими задачами и не тратил много энергии в аккамуляторе.

Comment: @oldzas, видел вашу задачу, с грузоперевозчиками, в пятницу:) Суть такова, что это одна из частей решения вашей. У Вас получается будет алгоритм таков, что

1. Имеем исходный массив точек и текущую позицию.
2. Для каждой точки производим $arr = search('Текущая позиция', 'Точка n', $Graph);
3. Смотрим наиболее малый массив из полученных пяти.
4. Удаляем исходную точку. Теперь исходная точка - та, расстояние до которой являлось самым малым
5. Повторяем действия пока количество точек для обхода != 0